# Ember this.render not working with controller param

Tags: ember.js, sidebar

i have a website with an {{outlet sidebar}} to display the navigation menu.

Because the navigation-menu have to be rendered independent of the current route, it starts to get complicated for me.

As a first try, use this code:

```
Ember.Route.reopen({
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render();
        this.render('layout/sidebar', {
            into: 'application',
            outlet: 'sidebar'
         });
    }
});
```

to overwrite the `renderTemplate` method of each route within my application.
And it worked fine.

But if I add the navigation-controller to be passed through, it does not work anymore.

```
Ember.Route.reopen({
    renderTemplate: function() {
        var navCont = this.controllerFor('navigation');

        this.render();
        this.render('layout/sidebar', {
            into: 'application',
            outlet: 'sidebar',
            controller: navCont
         });
    }
});
```

I checked the var navCont and it holds the navigation-controller as expected.

Does anyone know why it works without the controller?

Comment: I think you're missing the quotes around the controller name. http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_render

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you'd want to keep rendering the same outlet over and over with the same template.  You'd be better off just using `render` in the application template.

```
{{render 'navigation'}}
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jisuwuna/1/edit